# How to combine client and server on a DEV machine?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, gulp-connect

I'm developing a website with Angular.js, which uses an HTTP interceptor.

When I'm running the website on a DEV machine, I want my HTTP interceptor to write each HTTP request/response into a local PostgreSQL server.

I understand very well that I am mixing up the client and server sides, but this is strictly for development purposes, and always for a single local machine.

Is there any modern/standard/recommended way to do such a thing today?

P.S. Not sure if it is relevant, but I'm using `gulp-connect` to run my website locally.